# Armado de WAR con faltantes

Tags: java, genexus, war

Al intentar generar un **WAR** desde **GX17 u2** **java** para **Tomcat 7** No está incluyendo referencias a un módulo de encriptación que uso en el proyecto. Me doy cuenta porque cuando utilizo una funcionalidad que usa el módulo crashea como muestro aquí:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel$DynAjaxEvent.doInvoke(GXWebPanel.java:1089)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel$DynAjaxEvent.invoke(GXWebPanel.java:1119)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.webAjaxEvent(GXWebPanel.java:469)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.webExecuteEx(GXWebPanel.java:420)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.doExecute(GXWebPanel.java:443)
    at com.chlccestudios.testenc.doExecute(testenc.java:24)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callDoExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:242)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:189)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doPost(GXWebObjectStub.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/genexus/cryptography/symmetric/SymmetricBlockCipher
    at com.securityapi.genexuscryptography.SdtSymmetricBlockCipher.dodecrypt(SdtSymmetricBlockCipher.java:78)
    at com.chlccestudios.testenc_impl.e132S2(testenc_impl.java:754)
    ... 38 more

    com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:215)
    com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doPost(GXWebObjectStub.java:40)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1241)
```

Si subo la carpeta sin armar el **war** funciona correctamente. La pregunta es: ¿Cómo debo armar el war para que funcione correctamente?

**Actualización 12/08/21 9:40 hs**

Acá muestro el armado del war desde Genexus
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá muestro como incluí en el ClassPath los archivos:

GeneXusCryptography-17.2.0.jar
SecurityAPICommons-17.2.0.jar

De todas formar debería ser automática esta inclusión: por ser inferido desde el árbol de referencias a partir los objetos main que estoy incluyendo en el armado del war.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

lo que deberias hacer es copiar estos archivos del "/web/drivers" del environment, al "/WEB-INF/lib" del war o del server donde hayas hecho el deploy:

GeneXusCryptography-x.x.x.jar
SecurityAPICommons-x.x.x.jar

"*.x.x.x" refiere a la versión, el número depende de la versión de GeneXus que estés usando.

Saludos

Comment: Garcias Martin, es cierto que el war que se genera no incluye esos 2 archivos que mencionas. Pero se supone que genexus en su armado debería incluirlo automáticamente. Intenté agregarlos a mano en el ClassPath y tampoco lo incluye. Parece haber algún problema en el armado del war. Actualizo el post con nueva info. Gracias

Comment: Exacto, el armado deberia incluir esos archivos, lo que te respondi mas arriba es una solucion mientras la gente de genexus arregla este problema, que esta identificado y en proceso de correccion, seguramente para el proximo upgrade. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo correcto sería que modificaras el archivo que deberías de tener en el directorio web de tu modelo, con el nombre DeploymentUnit1_user.gxdproj (el nombre cambia si cambias el nombre del deployment).

Allí y asumiendo que tus jars están en el directorio lib de tu modelo, en el archivo, bajo el ItemsGroup deberías de incluir algo similar a esto para que se incluyan los jars indicados en el WAR:

```
<AdditionalFile Include="lib\GeneXusCryptography-17.2.0.jar">
    <RelativeTargetDir>WEB-INF/lib</RelativeTargetDir>
</AdditionalFile>
<AdditionalFile Include="lib\SecurityAPICommons-17.2.0.jar">
    <RelativeTargetDir>WEB-INF/lib</RelativeTargetDir>
</AdditionalFile>
```

En este artículo de la wiki se explica como [customizar el gxdproj](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?45672,Customize%20GeneXus%20Deployment%20capabilities).

Y en este hay un [ejemplo](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?36315,Sample%20content%20of%20DeploymentUnit_user.gxdproj%20File).